# Find specific int[] element inside ArrayList<int[]>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to find if a specific int[] exists within an ArrayList<int[]>, but when I use the method
.contains(value) it always returns false. I know that what is getting compared are the reference values.

I've tried converting each array element into a primitive hash, and storing it in another arrayList,  but this process takes too long and when I submit my code I go past the time limit.

Comment: "I know that what is getting returned is the reference and not the actual value." No you don't. What is returrned is `true` or `false`. The problem here is that `ArrayList` works on object equality, and `int[]` doesn't override `Object.equals()` to compare the contents of the arrays, so you get object *identity*, via the `==` operator; so `contains()` returns false as you must be supplying a different `int[]` from the one that is already in the `ArrayList`, *even if its element values are the same.* Moral: `int[]` isn't a great datatype to use in an `ArrayList`.

Comment: You're right, I didn't express myself properly. What I meant to say is that the values which are compared are the reference values, not the actual values.

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

As you already determined, `List.contains` will return results if the contained element and the given element are equal according to `Object.equals`. The problem is, arrays don't implement that the way you'd expect. You want `Arrays.equals` instead:

```
for (int[] element : myList) {
  if (Arrays.equals(element, target)) {
    // found it!
  }
}
```